# The angle between two tilted circles

Tags: geometry

Two-Part Question:

1.) Two circles (C1 and C2) sit tangent to both each other, and to the space between an inner circle C3 and an outer circle C4.  If r1 and r2 are known, how do we find theta?

[image: Circle Problem]

2.) Can this problem be "generalized" so that instead of the smaller circles occupying the space between C3 and C4, they lie in the space between two concentric ellipses?  Or, is that a different problem entirely?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$ are at a distance from the center of the great circle : 
$$
r_3=r_1+\left(\frac{r_2-r_1}{2} \right)=r_2-\left(\frac{r_2-r_1}{2} \right)
$$

---

[image]

$APE$ is  a rectangular triangle with $\angle EAP=\theta/2$ and we know $AE=r_3$ and $EP=r_3-r_1$. And we have: $\sin (\theta/2)=\frac{EP}{EA}$

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Should your comment be that the centers of C1 and C2 are at a distance from the center of the great circle: r3 = r2 - ((r2 - r1)/2)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I edit.:)

Comment: Thank you Emilio.  I still do not understand how to solve the problem, but I will keep your comment in mind.  I appreciate your input!

Comment: I added a figure.

Comment: Thank you Emilio, I understand now.  Not sure why I couldn't see that before when you added your first hint.